# Mostrar mensaje al estar en :after css

Tags: javascript, css

Buenas noches tengo una duda de como lograr desplegar el contenido del div a pantalla completa usando el efecto after de css este es solo un ejemplo de lo que deseo lograr solo que en lugar de onclick pueda usar after . y el mensaje sea mas grande y llamativo .

```
function myFunction() {
    var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

</script>
<style>
/* Contenedor del popup */
.popup {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* pop-up actual */
.popup .popuptext {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 160px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 8px 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 125%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -80px;
}

/* Muestra del Pop-up*/
.popup .popuptext::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

/* Cambio para mostrar/ocultar el contenedor del pop-up */
.popup .show {
    visibility: visible;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 1s;
    animation: fadeIn 1s
}

/* Animación del pop-up */
@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;} 
    to {opacity: 1;}
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    from {opacity: 0;}
    to {opacity:1 ;}
}
</style>
<center>
<br><br><br>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">¡Dame clic!
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">Texto del contenedor</span>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

lamentablemente sin el evento onclick, creo que seria imposible de todos modos 
podrias hacer asi :

```js
var el = document.getElementById("contenedor");

el.addEventListener("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked")
    if (this.hasAttribute("data-content")){
        this.removeAttribute("data-content");
    }else {
        this.setAttribute("data-content", "HELLO WORLD!");
    }
})
```

```css
#contenedor{
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#contenedor::after{
  position: absolute;
  top: -150%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  content: 0;
  background-color: red; 
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 24px;
  content: attr(data-content);
}
```

```html
<br><br>
<center>
   <div id="contenedor">click me!</div>
</center>
```

sabiendo que el pseudo-elemento no se ve hasta que no tenga contenido, usamos la función CSS `attr()` para permitirnos modificarlo mediante Javascript.

en este caso `content: attr(data-content)`, eso nos permite agregarle el atributo a nuestro elemento mediante el evento `onclick` simplemente usando la función `.setAttrubute()`.

**EDIT**

es extraño que no te funcione, le agregue un `console.log` para apreciar el evento : 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

espero que sea de ayuda.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta . pero al ejecutar tu codigo no hay ningún resultado .

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions en que sentido no hay ningun resultado ?

Comment: Al darle click  no da ningún resultado

Comment: puedes crear una etiqueta `<a>` y agregale un `:focus` para evitar el evento **click**